# Cannot access my extended Client from Event Listeners in Discord JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Let's say I have the following code:

```js
class CustomClient extends Client{
  constructor (data){
    super(data);
    this.customProperty = "hello";
  }
}

const client = new CustomClient(/*props*/);

client.on('message', message => { // message is an instance of the Message class
  console.log(message.client instanceof CustomClient) // false
  console.log(message.client instanceof Client) //true
  console.log(message.client.customProperty) //undefined
});
```

Clearly, received messages (and other discordjs events) aren't linked to CustomClient.

Is there a way I can 'extend' the default `Client` class so that `CustomClass.client` exists?

Comment: The current code you posted works fine for me: https://imgur.com/9Oo5VlA

Answer (score 1):

To use the class you need to initialize it.

```
class CustomClient extends Client{
  constructor (options){
      super(options)
    this.customProperty = "hello";
  }
}
var CustomClient = new CustomClient()
CustomClient.on(...)
```

Comment: Oh, you were 31 seconds faster than me. Have my upvote :)

Comment: Thx for your answer. However, I forgot to mention that I'm already using `super` to call the  base class. Plus, my client is already initialized (i updated the post)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call [`super`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super) constructor in your class. The following will work:

```js
class CustomClient extends Client {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.customProperty = 'hello';
  }
}

const client = new CustomClient();

client.on('message', (message) => {
  console.log(message.client instanceof CustomClient); // true
  console.log(message.client instanceof Client); //true
  console.log(message.client.customProperty); //hello
});
```

Comment: As I  commented on Cursed's answer, I forgot to mention that I'm using super and that an instance is already created (client is the instance)

Comment: That's strange, as I tested the above code and it works fine.